# C# WPF - Printing all files in directory that has ".xml" format - "could not find part of the path c#"

Tags: c#, wpf, file, directory

First of all - i googled the problem, and nothing good related seemed to come up.
Also it will probably seem to you that this question is a newbie one (and i must say i never had this problem when printing files in a directory.
I am pretty new to WPF in C#.

so..
I am having problems to Print all files in directory that has ".xml" format

**Here is my code to print the files in a directory (I am not talking about Recursive dirs and files print):**

```
    private void Load_ToolboxItems(string dirPath, string os, string version)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string command in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.xml"))
            {
                //load commands by OS compatibility
                MessageBox.Show(command);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**This is my window load event:**

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Combined " + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), @"\data\Windows\xp\"));
        MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName));
        Load_ToolboxItems(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName), @"\data\Windows\xp\"), "Windows", "XP");
    }
```

**Those are the outputs i get when running the program:**

1st messagebox- "Combined \data\Windows\xp\"

2nd messagebox-

```
C:\Users\Din\Din\Programming\Webs\Ended Projects\LogicalArm\Products\Visual Command Line\Visual_Command_Line-wpf_net3.5c_vs2010\Visual_Command_Line\bin\Release
```

3rd messagebox- "could not find part of the path 'C:\data\Windows\xp'."

**This is where the exe starts from:**

```
C:\Users\Din\Din\Programming\Webs\Ended Projects\LogicalArm\Products\Visual Command Line\Visual_Command_Line-wpf_net3.5c_vs2010\Visual_Command_Line\bin\Release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the \ from \data\windows\xp (the first \ that is).  Also be careful because your path is getting long.  There is a 260 character limit.

Path.Combine() know the directory separator character to use, so when you use it, the second parameter should not start with a .

Comment: yea i know about the 260 limit in windows and NTFS and thanks for the info about Path.Combine()

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".xml")
        MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

Not sure if your underlying issues is you are not getting the exact path you want, however the above should give you what you want from a listing of XML files stance.

Answer (score 0):

huh,

it always happens to me..

five minutes after i ask a question and after a long search i some-how find the problem myself..

I had problem with the path -_-

thanks for trying to help by the way